# adding an element only between two elements of given class (with css)

Tags: css

I'd like to know if it's possibile insert a new element between two elements of a given class. I'like to use only css, for exammpe:

```
<div class="a">
<div class="a">

<div class="b">
<div class="b">
<div class="b">
<div class="a">

<div class="b">
<div class="a">

<div class="b">
<div class="a">
```

I'd like to insert a new element between "a" and "b" (but not vice-versa):

```
<div class="a">
<div class="a">
<blank-line>

<div class="b">
<div class="b">
<div class="b">
<div class="a">
<blank-line>

<div class="b">
<div class="a">
<blank-line>

<div class="b">
<div class="a">
```

Comment: CSS cannot add HTML elements...that will require Javascript. However, if all you are trying to do is add space it is possible.

Comment: @Paulie_D With `content` property and `::before` or `::after` selector, it can.

Comment: That's a pseudo-element....which is intended for **styling** purposes not actual content.

Comment: Are you looking to add a *new element* or just a line-break? If you are looking for only a line break you can try this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jgjnp15c/) also.

Comment: @Paulie_D looks like the OP is just adding a blank line -- i.e. styling the content.

Comment: Then padding as per the answer(s) below would be the optimal way. No need to get too fancy. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this if you want only space between your elements:

```
.a + .b {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/980czfd0/2/)

---

If you want to take more control, use `::before`, something like this:

```
.a + .b::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/980czfd0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `content:` directive to add content (surprisingly!) before or after an html element:

```
/* Add something after every .a div: */
.a:after {
    content: "whatever you want to add in here"
}

/* Add something before every .b div: */
.b:before {
    content: "whatever you want to add in here"
}
```

Check out [some exciting things that css content can do](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/)! Note that **you cannot add HTML elements**--they will show up as text--but you can add attributes of the element you are targeting (see the linked page for more information).

If you just want a big space between `.a` and `.b` divs, you are best off using padding or a margin:

```
.a + .b {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted the `content`property **cannot** add HTML and should be used for **styling** purposes. It should **not** be used to adding actual content.

Comment: Added that info to clarify.